# Can 64-bit “PRINCEcore” practically be brute forced?

Tags: block-cipher, brute-force-attack, reference-request, key-size

There is a cipher called PRINCE proposed in ASIACRYPT two years ago.

See the paper: [“PRINCE – A Low-latency Block Cipher for
Pervasive Computing Applications”](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/529.pdf)

The cipher divides the 128-bit key into 64-bit k0 and k1. If I remove the key whitening at the beginning and end. Then the cipher is stripped down to PRINCEcore which only uses 64-bit k1. Is brute forcing the PRINCEcore practical?

Some clarifications:

- I dont worry about side channel attacks or fault attacks.
- I have seen several attacks on PRINCE (and also PRINCEcore), but they are not significantly better than brute force.

Comment: Once you're over the initial development cost of custom hardware, this isn't very expensive. I think it's about as much work as mining a single bitcoin block at the current difficult. Or differently said, it would take the current bitcoin mining network only a few minutes. Should be 10k USD or something of that magnitude.

Comment: Removed key-whitening… in that case, let me ask: ***“What research have you done?”***

Comment: @e-sushi, I am sorry. Could you elaborate a little bit? I am not trying to make a trivial case. I am just curious if that is still secure.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, Thank you for the comments. Is there any related references that I can take a look?

Comment: @dannycrane Depends how exactly you define “secure”. As far as I know, full PRINCE has not been broken yet. Nevertheless, you might find [this paper](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/blondeau/PDF/prince.pdf) and [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/043.pdf) interesting. There’s more of that out there… which is why I asked what you’ve researched – as I don’t want to waste your time with stuff you might already be aware of.

Comment: @e-sushi, thank you for the comment. Now I am getting familiar with the terminology here ;). Yes, I came across those references and there is one more [here](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/089.pdf). I have not seen any attacks on PRINCEcore that is significantly faster than brute force. What is the effort required to do a brute force attack on PRINCEcore? I have seen people using rainbow tables to break DES(56-bit key) pretty fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRINCEcore is a 64-bit block cipher with a 64-bit key $k_1$. PRINCE is a 64-bit block cipher with a 128-bit key $k_0||k_1$ built from PRINCEcore as
$$\operatorname{PRINCE}((k_0||k_1),x)=\operatorname{PRINCEcore}(k_1,(x\oplus k_0))\oplus P(k_0)$$ where $P(k_0)$ is given as $(k_0\ggg1)\oplus(k_0\gg63)$ which I read as: rotate the 64-bit $k_0$ right by one bit, then replace the rightmost bit by its XOR with the second leftmost one; making $P$ a mapping.

That extension from PRINCEcore to PRINCE is reminescent of the extension from DES to DESX, analyzed by Joe Kilian and Phillip Rogaway in [*How to protect DES against exhaustive key search (an analysis of DESX)*](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/desx.pdf). At least, that construction greatly improves the resistance to exhaustive key search, and **I do not see that PRINCE could be practically brute-forced with work commensurate to brute-force of PRINCEcore** (that is, near $2^{63}$ encryptions).

Note: The best motivation I can find for $P$ is that the rotation it contains avoids a cancellation of $k_0$ in some common operating modes, like OFB, CBC, CFB.. However, by rotating the output of PRINCE, we can cancel that rotation. And the single-bit XOR in $P$ does not seem to add much security.